# All Lines are Dotted!

Tags: gimp

When using GIMP, and I select a pencil or a brush, all my lines are dotted! How do I fix this?

Comment: Why was the answer added to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Brushes window all the way to the bottom set `Spacing` to a lower value.